What hook can be used when click on "Remove Item" in cart
I need to run code to update a database table (not part of wp and wc) when user clicks on "Remove item" in the cart of woocommerce. What hook can be used to achieve this. I have tried woocommerce_remove_cart_item unsuccessfully; nothing happens.
The same I do when user adds a product to the cart. This works well. So, I just need the opposite hook to woocommerce_add_to_cart.
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_remove', 'andom_woocommerce_remove_from_cart_action', 10, 2);

function andom_woocommerce_remove_from_cart_action($cart_item_key, $cart){

//preparing vars

.....

  $outConsumption = array(
    'id' => $resultId,
    'pId' => $product_id,
    'cId' => $current_user_id,
    'pRationType' => $curProdRatType,
    'pQuantity' => $request_quantity,
    'pMonth' => $pOrderMonth,
    'pYear' => $pOrderYear,
  );

  andom_cart_consumption_handler('Delete', $outConsumption);

}


So I think I solved it. No clue if there is better way. Here the hook:
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_removed', 'andom_woocommerce_remove_from_cart_action', 10, 2);
//add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_remove', 'andom_woocommerce_remove_from_cart_action', 9, 2);

function andom_woocommerce_remove_from_cart_action($cart_item_key, $cart){

  //$removed_items = WC()->cart->get_removed_cart_contents();

  //$product_id = $removed_items[$cart_item_key]['product_id'];
  $product_id = $cart->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['product_id'];

  //$product_id = $cart->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['product_id'];
  $quantity = $cart->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['quantity'];
  //$quantity = 1;
  $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $current_user_meta = get_user_meta($current_user_id);
  $idCard = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'id_card', true );
  $adults = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'adults', true );
  $children = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'children', true );

  //$pOrderMonth = '4';
  $pOrderMonth = $cart->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['thwepof_options']['order_month']['value'];
  //$pOrderYear = '2024';
  $pOrderYear = $cart->removed_cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['thwepof_options']['order_year']['value'];

  $resultId = get_consumption_id($current_user_id, $product_id, $pOrderMonth, $pOrderYear) == False ? '0' : get_consumption_id($current_user_id, $product_id, $pOrderMonth, $pOrderYear);

  $resultQy = get_consumption_quantity($current_user_id, $product_id, $pOrderMonth, $pOrderYear, $quantity) == False ? '0' : get_consumption_quantity($current_user_id, $product_id, $pOrderMonth, $pOrderYear, $quantity);

  $outConsupmtion = array(
    'id' => $resultId,
    'pId' => $product_id,
    'cId' => $current_user_id,
    'pRationType' => $curProdRatType,
    'pQuantity' => $quantity,
    'pMonth' => $pOrderMonth,
    'pYear' => $pOrderYear,
  );

  if ($resultQy - $quantity == 0){

    andom_cart_consumption_handler('Delete', $outConsupmtion);

  } else {

    $outConsupmtion['pQuantity'] = $resultQy - $quantity;

    andom_cart_consumption_handler('Update', $outConsupmtion);

  }

  // wp_redirect( get_page_by_path( 'cart' ) );
  // exit();

}


So this sorted the issue out, however still spits an error. See picture.
What could this be?

